# Callback not executing in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, callback

I wrote a method that is supposed to execute a callback, but the callback isnt being executed:

```
buildTable('lt', 'viewltDetails', commonTireColumns, function(error) {
if(error) {
    console.log(error);
} else {
    console.log('calculating');
    calculatedPricing();
}
});
```

My buildTable function - it essentially creates a datatable using the aldeed-tabular package:

```
function buildTable(tblName, detailsBtn, columnDetails) {
var columns = [];
for(var key in columnDetails) {
      columns.push({
        data: columnDetails[key].data, 
        title: columnDetails[key].title, 
        width: columnDetails[key].width
      });
    };
columns.push({
    title: "Quantity",
    tmpl: Meteor.isClient && Template.itemQuantityCell,
    width: "2%"
});
columns.push({
    title: "Details",
    tmpl: Meteor.isClient && Template[detailsBtn],
});
columns.push({
    title: "Action",
    tmpl: Meteor.isClient && Template.addToCartCell,
});

TabularTables[tblName] = new Tabular.Table({
    name: tblName,
    changeSelector: function(selector, userId) {
        return selector;
    },
    collection: Products,
    pub: "tabular_Products",
    columns: columns,
    extraFields: ['priceFET', 'invoicePrice', 'category']
})
};
```

The `buildTable` function works fine, but it's not executing the `console.log('calculating')` and `calculatePricing()` commands, although the function isn't throwing any errors.

My calculatePricing function looks like:

```
calculatedPricing: function() {
    var price = 300;
    return price;
};
```

Can someone help? Thanks!!

Comment: You'll almost definitely need to share `buildTable` so we can see how the callback should be invoked and what `error` is expected to be

Comment: You are probably not invoking the callback properly in ```buildTable```

Comment: Your `calculatedPricing` definition has wrong syntax. _FYI_: `calculatedPricing` is not a callback in your code

Comment: I added my buildTable() code!

Comment: so ... where exactly is buildTable calling anything? the fourth argument (which is the callback in your first code snippet) isn't even defined (not that that is a problem as such)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try like this.
You add a calback function but you don't have it at a parameter so you never call it on your function.

```
 function buildTable(tblName, detailsBtn, columnDetails, callback) {
         //your code here
         if(typeof callback === "function"){
           callback();
         }
    }
```

Comment: callback in example expects an argument indicating error

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an argument for the callback to your buildTable function

change:

```
function buildTable(tblName, detailsBtn, columnDetails) {
```

to:

```
function buildTable(tblName, detailsBtn, columnDetails, callback) {
```

then, call it:

```
callback(someError);
```

Comment: callback in example expects an argument indicating error

Comment: good point, but I didn't see where an error is being caught, just trying to provide direction here...